# Holo theme make my button bigger

Tags: android, button, layout

I have a little concern when applying the holo theme on devices with api >= version 11
My custom buttons get bigger (in height, the width seems to be the same)

This is without holo them
[image]

this is with holo them
[image]

May someone tell me what is causing this? and If it is possible to keep the same button size as without holo theme?

ps: this is my button shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#F000" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#BB000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#5b5bcd"
        android:endColor="#6f6fcf"
        android:startColor="#4747e0"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

and this is how I apply it on my button (that is in a linear hirozontal linearLayout with a weight of 0.8)

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/addplayer"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button_selector"
            android:text="Add player" />
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android's Holo theme sets a minWidth and minHeight in the system styles.xml resource for Holo.Widget.Button which specifies rules in addition to those used by the non-holo button, Widget.Button. Even with a small button title, the button will take up 64x48dip in Android 4.2.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sample_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Z"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:minHeight="1dp"
    android:minWidth="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    style="@style/CustomButton"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Make below xml files
2. You can apply custom theme in the menifest

Like this - android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"

[In the values folder]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Inherits the default theme for pre-HC (no action bar) -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

[In the values-v11 folder]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Inherits the Holo theme with no action bar; no other styles needed. -->
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomHoloLightButtonStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomHoloLightButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
    <item name="android:minHeight">1dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">1dip</item>
</style>    

</resources>
```